# How to clear plots to avoid memory leak?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting the a large number of grids of figures, and I get the warning:

> /home/michael/miniconda2/envs/pt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:537:
>   RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created
>   through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained
>   until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control
>   this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning).

More importantly, I get a memory leak. How should I clear the plots properly to eliminate this leak?

```
def place_fig(values, rows=1, columns=1, r=0, c=0, label='test'):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((rows, columns), (r, c))
    ax.hist(values, label=label)
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')


def plot_grid(arrays, path=None, filename=''):
    plt.figure()
    for c in range(5):
        for array, r in zip(arrays[c], range(5)):
            place_fig(array, rows=5, columns=5, r=r, c=c)
    plt.savefig(path + filename)
    plt.clf()


def plot_layers(path=None, i=0, values_3d=None):

    array1 = []
    array2 = []
    array3 = []
    array4 = []
    array5 = []

    array_list = [array1, array2, array3, array4, array5]

    for j in range(5):
        for array, values in zip(array_list, values_3d[j]):
            array.append(values)

    plot_grid([array1, array2, array3, array4, array5], path=path, filename='iter_{:d}'.format(i))


for i in range(1000):
    values_3d = np.random.randn(5, 5, 10000)
    plot_layers(path='plots/', i=i, values_3d=values_3d)
```

Comment: Does matplotlib.pyplot.close(fig) not work in this case? https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decide:

- Do you want to create one single figure (`plt.figure()` is called once), then `clear` the figure: `plt.clf()`
- Do you want to create a new figure in each step (`plt.figure()` is called each step), then `close` the figure. `plt.close()`

(Currently, you're doing half/half, hence all the figures will stay open and flood the memory.)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. plot_grid generates a grid of figures (histograms), and saves it as a single image. This happens 1000 times. I guess I'm confused about what is a 'figure' in matplotlib. Can you please explain what's the difference between the two options you mentioned?

Comment: A figure is the object that gets shown upon `plt.show()` or that is saved upon `plt.savefig()`. You create 1000 of those objects, without ever removing them from memory after you don't need them any more. It's like a sheet of paper. Option 1 would be a single sheet; you erase its content after every draw and draw something new onto it. Option 2 would be to take a new sheet for each drawing; but afterwards make sure to throw it in the bin. In both cases you don't have 1000 sheets of paper piling up on your desk.

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks! Would it be possible to modify my code that it uses option 1, so basically create a figure once, draw plots, save the figure, clear the plots with clf(), then draw other plots in the same figure, save this modified figure, clear the plots again, etc?

Comment: I guess my question is - can I create a figure in plot_layers function, then pass it as an argument to plot_grid function, and clear it in plot_grid after saving?

Comment: Absolutely. It looks like you just need to move the `plt.figure()` line to that function - but of course without runnable code I can't be 100% sure.